# Compare strings and remove more general pattern in Perl

Tags: algorithm, perl

I have an array of strings that numbers, possibly separated by forward slashes, e.g. `754` or `754/128`. These strings can have an undefined length, in other words: something such as the following is possible: `1234/34/21/120/3`. In the array I want to only keep the more specialised patterns that *contain* other patterns. For instance, in the first example above `754/128` contains `754`, so `754` can be removed from the array.

This concept of *containing* is as broad as one would expect, maybe even broader: it is similar to how you look at a directed graph where each slash in the pattern refers to a step forward. the contained pattern can be of arbitrary length as long as it is inside the containing pattern one way or another. This means that the *small* path can occur in any (chronologically correct) form. For instance, `903/900` is contained in `903/902/900` even though the pattern is 'split open'. One way to visualise this is: in the small path we go from point A to point B. In the larger path we also go from pont A to B but we make a stop at C. The larger path visits *more* places than the small path without missing out on anything. As a consequence, the smaller path can occur in any split-up form - as long as the order of the path is respected. As an example:

```
2/5 - 1/2/3/4/5
# included
5/2 - 1/2/3/4/5
# not included
```

What I mean here is that the position of the 'contained' items should be identical in the large path. For instance: `1/3/2` 'matches' in `1/5/3/4/2` because the order is identical in the small and large path: `1` comes in a position before `3`, which in turn is in some position before `2`. `1/2/3`, `2/1/3` and so on would NOT match the larger path `1/5/3/4/2` even though they are valid paths with the same items. This is because the order of occurrence is different.

The above example also illustrates that the items in the small pattern can occur *any where* in the large pattern; not only in the first and last position or in subsequent positions. In other words, all included paths for `1/2/3/4` are:

```
1/2
1/2/3
1/3
1/4
2/3
2/3/4
2/4
3/4
```

I am looking for an **efficient** way to remove paths in a given array that are included in others from that same array.

I got [this far](http://ideone.com/MeHg0d), but I'm not sure how I should efficiently check the *contains* relationship between two items.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @arr = ("903/900", "903/902/900", "903/904/902/901", "903/904/902/908/900", "903");
my @res = ();

OUTER: for (my $i = 0; $i < @arr; $i++) {
    my $first = $arr[$i];
    my $j = $i+1;
    INNER: while($j < @arr) {
        my $second = $arr[$j];
        &compare_paths($first, $second);
        $j++;
    }
}

sub compare_paths {
    my ($first, $second) = @_;

    @first_items = split(/\//, $first);
    @second_items = split(/\//, $second);

    # Compare values from 1 and 2
}
```

The expected output for the code above would be

```
@res = ("903/904/902/901", "903/904/902/908/900");
```

Reasons for removal:

- `903/900` contained in `903/902/900`
- `903/902/900` contained in `903/904/902/908/900`
- `903` contained in `903/904/902/901`

How can I implement such algorithm efficiently? My main idea would be to check if an item of `@first_items` is a present in `$second`, if not continue, but if so check if a second item is also present and if so: check its substring position. This has to be larger than the first items substring position. Continue for each item (and the other way around for `@second_items` and `$first`) until all strings are matched. (If it helps for speed, the initial array can be swapped for a hash with the former array as the keys.)

Comment: Note that tag suggestions are welcome, as I wasn't sure how to tag this.

Comment: Seeing labels on your loops that aren't used are a sign something's awry here. What else have you tried?

Comment: @tadman I added those because I was going to add some loop exits in case a match (*containment*) was found, but of course I could only add that after I have a subroutine that matches. Perhaps the subroutine could return `1` when a match occurred when `$first` is in `$second`, `2` when `$second` is in `$first` and `0` when no matches were found. In case of `1` or `2`, remove the corresponding item.

Comment: @zdim I'm sorry, completely forgot about this. +1 and accepted, I'm sorry for the wait! I'll award you the bounty because of the extensiveness. It's a great answer!

Comment: @BramVanroy That's completely OK -- there are things other than SO :)  Thank you very much for the response! I'd also suggest to make sure to review all material on this page.  It's a good question, and there's a lot in all answers :)

Comment: @BramVanroy I just realized the bounty thing -- that is very _very_ nice of you.  Thank you very much for caring. Hopefully this also brings yet more and better answers.

Comment: @zdim No problem at all. You put *a lot* of effort in testing, writing, benchmarking. It's the least I can do! (I doubt anyone can come up with a better answer! I'll award you the bounty as soon as I can.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that there are general algorithms that can account for this problem, and probably libraries that can be leveraged.  However, here is a hand-rolled one.

First, we sort the array by the number of terms in the path . Then we go up that array, comparing each element with all longer ones. This way each path is excluded at earliest opportunity.

The comparison is between arrays obtained by splitting on `/`. It checks whether all elements of the smaller array are in the larger one as *an exact sub-sequence*, so that the larger one would yield the smaller one by only removing elements (without rearrangements).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr = qw(902/904 903/900 903/902/900 903/904/902/901 
             903/904/902/908/900 903);
my @sorted = sort { (split '/', $a) > (split '/', $b) } @arr;
my @primes;

OUTER:
for my $i (0..$#sorted) {
    for my $j ($i+1..$#sorted) {
        next OUTER if is_contained($sorted[$i], $sorted[$j]);
    }
    push @primes, $sorted[$i];
} 
print "@primes\n";

sub is_contained 
{
    my ($small, $large) = @_;
    my @small = split '/', $small;
    my @large = split '/', $large;

    # There can be no duplicates so equal-length paths are distinct
    return 0 if @small == @large;

    # Indices of elements of @small in @large cannot decrease
    my ($match, $index) = (0, 0);
    for my $sm (@small) {
        for my $i (0..$#large) {
            $sm == $large[$i] || next;
            return 0 if $i < $index;  # out of order
            $index = $i;
            $match = 1;
            last;
        }
        return 0 if not $match;       # $sm from @small not in @large
        $match = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Prints the line: `902/904 903/904/902/901 903/904/902/908/900`.

A note on how we check that the `@smaller` matches a subsequence in `@larger`.

Once a `@smaller` element is found in `@larger`, its index in `@larger`
cannot be lower than the one found previously. An element must come *after* the previous one, not before. See a different procedure below.

So with `2/7/5` and `1/2/5/7/8`, first `2` is found at index *1*, then `7` at index *3*, then `5` but at index *2*. The subsequence `2-5-7` does not match `2-7-5`.  I added `902/904` to data to test for this.

---

This is an alternate procedure for checking whether a path is contained in another.

Once it finds an element of `@smaller` in `@larger` it searches for the next one *starting from the next index* in `@larger`.  This way it skips the searched part of the path, but it cannot detect out-of-order elements early either.

With the example of `2/7/5` and `1/2/5/7/8`, after it found `7` at index *3* it starts from index *4* and detects failure by *not finding* a `5` in the rest of the target path.

```
sub is_contained_2 
{
    my @large = split '/', $_[0];
    my @small = split '/', $_[1];

    # Is @small found in @large as an exact sub-sequence?
    my ($match, $j) = (0, 0); 
    for my $sm (@small) {
        for my $i ($j..$#large) {
            $sm == $large[$i] || next;
            $j = $i+1, $match = 1;
            last;
        }
        return 0 if not $match;
        $match = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is *slower* (by 10-15%) for this data set, see benchmark with a comment below.

---

I benchmarked the two array-based versions here and [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s regex+trie. So far I have used *only the specific data set* from the question, with `902/904` added.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
my $secs_to_run = shift || 10; 
my @arr = ('902/904', '903/900', '903/902/900', '903/904/902/901', 
           '903/904', '/902/908/900', '903');

# sorted array checked shorter-to-longer, manual iterations
sub contained {  
    my ($rarr) = @_; my @arr = @$arr;
    # program copied from this post
    return \@primes;
}
sub is_contained { ... }   # copied

# Same program, but using is_contained_2()
sub contained_2 {  ... }
sub is_contained_2 { ... }

# Regex-trie, copied from ikegami's post
sub add { my $p = \shift; $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_, ''; }
sub as_pat { my $trie = shift; ... }  # copied

sub regex_trie { 
    my ($rpaths) = @_; my @paths = @$rpaths;
    # program copied from ikegami's post
    return \@filtered_paths;
}

cmpthese(-$secs_to_run, {
    containted  => sub { my $rprimes   = contained(\@arr)  },
    cont_next   => sub { my $rprimes   = contained_2(\@arr)  },
    regex_trie  => sub { my $rfiltered = regex_trie(\@arr)  },
});
```

With `bench_cont.pl 300`, on a newer workstation-laptop (2.5GHz) with v5.16

```
              Rate regex_trie  cont_next containted
regex_trie 15264/s         --       -15%       -27%
cont_next  17946/s        18%         --       -14%
containted 20939/s        37%        17%         --
```

on an older server (2.8GHz) with v5.16

```
              Rate regex_trie  cont_next containted
regex_trie 11750/s         --       -13%       -27%
cont_next  13537/s        15%         --       -16%
containted 16042/s        37%        19%         --
```

on an older server (3.5GHz) with v5.10

```
              Rate  cont_next regex_trie containted
cont_next  12266/s         --       -17%       -17%
regex_trie 14832/s        21%         --        -0%
containted 14845/s        21%         0%         --
```

This surprised me, as I expected the regex-based solution to be fastest.

I expect the trend to reverse for data composed of longer paths, having more distinct (not contained) paths, with containment found later in the path, and with a few out-of-order dismissals.

I'll add tests once I get to generate such data, or once it is provided.

---

To track some of the processing change the body to

```
use feature 'say';

OUTER:
for my $i (0..$#sorted) {
    say "Check $sorted[$i]";
    for my $j ($i+1..$#sorted) {
        my $is_inside = is_contained($sorted[$i], $sorted[$j]);
        say "\t$is_inside: $sorted_arr[$i] inside $sorted_arr[$j]";
        next OUTER if $is_inside;
    }
    push @primes, $sorted[$i];
}
say "\nNot contained: @primes";
```

This prints

```
Check 903
        0: 903 vs. 902/904
        1: 903 vs. 903/900
Check 902/904
        0: 902/904 vs. 903/900
        0: 902/904 vs. 903/902/900
        0: 902/904 vs. 903/904/902/901
        0: 902/904 vs. 903/904/902/908/900
Check 903/900
        1: 903/900 vs. 903/902/900
Check 903/902/900
        0: 903/902/900 vs. 903/904/902/901
        1: 903/902/900 vs. 903/904/902/908/900
Check 903/904/902/901
        0: 903/904/902/901 vs. 903/904/902/908/900
Check 903/904/902/908/900

Not contained: 902/904 903/904/902/901 903/904/902/908/900
```

Comment: In fact, the input data does not contain duplicates, this is a certainty. Therefore, it seems to me that we can just check the size of two paths and if they are the same, skip the `is_contained` because that would simply not be possible. [Something like this](http://ideone.com/e7WKR8), but I'm sure you can write it in a better way. Question, though, in your sort block you the result of split in list context, shouldn't this be in a scalar context?

Comment: @BramVanroy  Yes, that would help, probably only a little.  (How often can that happen?)  But it should be added, first thing in the sub.  There are certainly other low-level tweaks to speed it up, but that shouldn't make a difference. The algorithm is simple and doesn't waste time (as far as I can tell).  However, the question is whether there is some higher level one, for example some graph theory based theorem or such.  Before all this, I'd test. This may well be good enough.

Comment: @BramVanroy  OK, good to know -- I'll add that check. As for context -- with `@a > @b` there is the scalar context, imposed by `>`.  So lengths of arrays are taken and compared.

Comment: @BramVanroy  I added the test for equal-length paths, in the function.  If it's before, it saves a function call -- but only rarely, when they happen to be of equal length.  Most of the time it does an extra `split` (twice).

Comment: @BramVanroy I passed up on hashes right away since in this problem order is important.  Hashes are great for coordinated lookups and such, but order is thrown away.  I don't exactly understand what you are saying -- I will think about it.

Comment: @BramVanroy  Btw, typically how many strings do you need to process this way, and (typically) how long are they?  How much do their lengths vary?

Comment: After trying some stuff out, I indeed couldn't get around the fact that hashes aren't ordered, which would always get you in trouble I think. So never mind what I said before. The amount of strings that need to compared at a time this way is small, somewhere between 10 and 12. However, this process is repeated millions of times (for different strings). How long are they: from what I've seen in my data, paths can be from 1 to 10 items long. (But each item can be a number in the millions, e.g. `12346579/1263/13256897/65498746/6548979`.)

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help so far by the way! This should be one of my last questions. You said that the length comparison would cause an extra split (twice), but I don't see why that's the case. The split is done any way in the subroutine, right?

Comment: @BramVanroy  Yes, it is done in the subroutine.  To check path lengths I need two splits, one for each string (or regex's on `/`).  So if I do a check for equal lengths before the sub and it fails -- vast majority of cases -- then I go in the sub and do the splits, as normal analysis.  So the check before the sub is just an excessive split(s) (or regex), most of the time.  And when it helps, it only saves a single subroutine call (in comparison with having the check inside of it), or a single processing pop (when there is no check).

Comment: @BramVanroy  I added a line of code that mysteriously disappeared when I pasted the code here.  It exits from the inner-most loop in the sub once a match is found (of course). The line is `last;`.  It improves the runtime by about 5% (but it'd be a bit more with longer strings).  I'm benchmarking, may add code if there is any significant improvement.

Comment: @BramVanroy  I added an alternate procedure for checking whether a path is contained in another.  It is slower for this data set, but is probably faster if data is different (commented).  I benchmarked all this carefully, and the main solution is faster by 10-15% than the alternate, and by around 35% than the regex-trie based one (what surprised me).  Again, _on this data set_.  By what you said your real data isn't very different, but all this should be checked with the actual data.

Comment: @BramVanroy    Also, benchmarks confirmed that low-level tweaks don't matter.  It's a small number of short strings (your real data is). What does matter is doing repeated processing in parallel on 30+ cores on a server (or 8 or so on a desktop/laptop).

Answer (score 1):

If `a/b/c` is path, you want to remove the paths for which the following is true:

```
"/$path" =~ m{ ^ (?:/a)?+ (?:/b)?+ (?:/c)?+ \z }x  &&  $path ne 'a/b/c'
```

That can also be written as

```
"/$path" =~ m{ ^ (?:/a)?+ (?:/b)?+ (?:/c)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/b/c ) }x
```

If both `a/b/c`, `a/i/j`, `a/x/y` and `d/e/f` are paths, you want to remove the paths for which the following is true:

```
"/$path" =~ m{
      ^ (?:/a)?+ (?:/b)?+ (?:/c)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/b/c )
   |  ^ (?:/a)?+ (?:/i)?+ (?:/j)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/i/j )
   |  ^ (?:/a)?+ (?:/x)?+ (?:/y)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/x/y )
   |  ^ (?:/d)?+ (?:/e)?+ (?:/f)?+ \z (?<! ^ /d/e/f )
}x
```

We removed alot of the backtracking by using the possessive modifier (`+`), but there is still a possibility for backtracking because of the common prefixes. So let's remove them!

```
"/$path" =~ m{
   ^
   (?: (?:/a)?+ (?: (?:/b)?+ (?:/c)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/b/c )
                |   (?:/i)?+ (?:/j)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/i/j )
                |   (?:/x)?+ (?:/y)?+ \z (?<! ^ /a/x/y )
                )
   |   (?:/d)?+ (?:/e)?+ (?:/f)?+ \z (?<! ^ /d/e/f )
   )
}x
```

Now we have an efficient solution!

---

The following uses a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to do this to remove the common prefixes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub add {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_, '';
}

sub as_pat {
   my $trie = shift;

   my @sub_pats =
      map { $_ eq '' ? '' : $_ . as_pat($trie->{$_}) }
         keys(%$trie);

   if (@sub_pats == 1) {
      return $sub_pats[0];
   } else {
      return '(?:'.join('|', @sub_pats).')';
   }
}


my @paths = ( "903/900", "903/902/900", "903/904/902/901", "903/904/902/908/900", "903" );

my $trie;
add($trie, map({ "(?:/\Q$_\E)?+" } split qr{/}), "\\z(?<!^/\Q$_\E)" )
   for @paths;

my $pat = as_pat($trie);
my $re = qr{^(?:$pat)};

my @filtered_paths = grep { "/$_" !~ /$re/ } @paths;

say for @filtered_paths;
```

Say N is the number of paths, and O(M) bounds the length of the paths. Like earlier answers, this one completes in O(N<sup>2</sup> * M<sup>2</sup>) time, so it doesn't scale any better. However, I believe you will find mine faster should you benchmark them.

Comment: Some time ago I've dug into the theory of prefix trees, but I'd never think to use them for this use case -- I've never used in practice either. I very much like it (+1) but it is, as you probably would agree on, not the most readable solution! As I'm sharing my code with others, this might not be ideal.

Comment: I did benchmark them, expecting yours to be faster, as needed iterations go in C (along with a lot of other code economy).  However, the result is that the array-based one is faster by around 35%. Even the added alternate (array) version, which continues search from the previously found index, is slower than the main one (by 10-15%) and a little faster than regex.  I don't understand why.  This is a specific data set, but still.  I used `Benchmark`, copy-pasted codes, and ran it a number of times, even for 5 minutes each.

Comment: Cool, but as always, I want to see the benchmark code before I put any stock in it -- too easy to get wrong

Comment: Added a benchmark to my answer, for this data set only.  I'll run it with other data, once I get to generate (longer and more complex) data, or if @BramVanroy can supply a few batches of his realistic data.  (Which in my understanding isn't too different.)

Answer (score 1):

To optimize what you have so far, I'd suggest that you *pre-split* all elements of the array (and then re-merge them later):

```
@arr = map [split "/", $_], @arr;
```

With that done:

```
sub contains(\@\@) {
    my ($larger_ref, $smaller_ref) = @_;

    return '' if @$larger_ref <= @$smaller_ref;

    my ($i, $j) = 0;
    while ($i < @$larger_ref && $j <= @$smaller_ref) {
        ++$j if $larger_ref->[$i] == $smaller_ref->[$j];
        ++$i;
    }

    return $j == @$smaller_ref;
}

I: for (my $i = 0; $i < @arr; ++$i) {
    J: for (my $j = 0; $j < @arr; ++$j) {
        next J if $j == $i;
        next I if contains @{$arr[$j]}, @{$arr[i]};
    }
    push @res, join '/', @{$arr[$i]};
}
```

There are some potential further optimizations you can make in `contains` (for example, it might make sense to abort early if/when `@$larger_ref - $i < @$smaller_ref - $j`), but you'd want to test: they might turn out to be pessimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Say N is the number of paths, and O(M) bounds the length of the paths, the earlier answers complete in O(N<sup>2</sup> * M<sup>2</sup>) time.

The following solution is O(N * 2<sup>M</sup>). This means it can handle very large numbers of paths much much more efficiently, as long as the paths are rather short (because it effectively becomes O(N<sup>2</sup>) vs O(N)). It does require far more memory than the solutions in the earlier answers.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub fetch {
   my $trie = shift;
   for (@_, '') {
      return () if !$trie;
      $trie = $trie->{$_}
   }

   return $trie;
}


sub add {
   local *_helper = sub {
      my $trie_ptr = \shift;
      my $exact    =  shift;
      if (@_) {
         my $lead = shift(@_);
         _helper($$trie_ptr->{$lead}, $exact, @_);
         _helper($$trie_ptr, 0, @_);
      } else {
         if ($exact) {
            $$trie_ptr->{''} ||= 1;
         } else {
            $$trie_ptr->{''} = 2;
         }
      }
   };

   my $trie_ptr = \shift;
   return _helper($$trie_ptr, 1, @_);
}


my @paths = ( "903/900", "903/902/900", "903/904/902/901", "903/904/902/908/900", "903" );

my @split_paths = map [ split qr{/} ], @paths;

my $trie;
add($trie, @$_)
   for @split_paths;

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
print(Dumper($trie));

my @filtered_paths =
   map join('/', @$_),
      grep { fetch($trie, @$_) == 1 }
         @split_paths;

say for @filtered_paths;
```